# subdomain user authentation in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

My main domain is example.com and it's develop using drupal 7. Now my second domain is sub.example.com and it's non drupal site.

sub.example.com developed with angularjs and html,css.

Now I want to use drupal users authentication to my all subdomain apps.

**For Information-**

I am using jdrupal, then I can collect all non authenticate data like - node information, taxonomy information. But, I can't collect current logged in user information.

I googling lots, but everybody say **"Although I have never tried either in a subdomain, but I know others have done it."**

Nobody can't help clearly. so, I asked here for get actual solution to solve my problem.

Thanx.
Waiting for answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Create a module with a route that receives 2 parameters: username & password, and return if login was correct. See user_authenticate https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_authenticate/7.x
2. Send the login information (server side) with something like CURL and get the login result.

And that's it :)

PD: Tell me if you need more detail.